# How would you filter the DC input suitable for use to bias/power an LNA?

Tags: amplifier, rf, filter, biasing, low-noise-amplifier

We are building a transmit/receive module for the 144MHz and 440MHz bands.  As I understand, a good LNA can provide poor performance if the environment or the bias voltage is too noisy.

- What are the best practices for things like filtering and preventing outside noise to get good success with an LNA implementation?
- Other considerations?

This is the LNA we are looking at using: [Qorvo QPL9547](https://www.qorvo.com/products/d/da007268)

Comment: Best performance with design and layout shown with dedicated LDO and 100 pF NPO

Comment: while a good choice for 440 MHz, really check with a ruler whether the "Gain vs Frequency" chart suggests sufficient gain at 144 MHz. I get rough 21 dB. Might be enough, might not, depends on you :)

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, Do you recommend a particular LDO or type of LDO for this purpose?

Comment: Since there aren’t any specs for sensitivity to PSRR which unlike Op amps tend to be poorer , important at low signal levels for effects on SNR,and phase noise, this may be overkill but here are some ideas, https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/3/3657.html?s_kwcid=AL!8732!3!517443871860!b!!g!!&utm_source=googleads&utm_campaign=FY21_Q1_2020_JUL_MSS-LPMicros_AMER_MicrosAdWords_EN&gclid=CjwKCAjwqIiFBhAHEiwANg9szlXvrqihSSSdtpABprW8v0V5E8eIGWzyocWa5hjr634kXCdbSty3bhoCnnQQAvD_BwE